# C++ in NetBeans shows errors(unable to resolve identifiers) but the code runs fine

Tags: c++, netbeans

I just started coding C++ in NetBeans. I have a working code.(compiled fine , run fine) The problem is the code will show some errors(unable to resolve identifiers).

[image]

why this is happening. ? The code works fine. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: probably your ide don't know where to search for the files.

Comment: that means ? how can i fixed it?

Comment: One off-topic question: Why do you use `std::qsort()` having the clear, faster, and easier to use `std::sort()`?

Comment: Actually it's a code which i get as an answer to one of my previous questions. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931669/sort-a-2d-array-in-c-using-built-in-functionsor-any-other-method). :)

Comment: NetBeans is the worst c++ environment I had to use. Lasted a day till I changed back to VIM.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project and then rebuild it.